# css hover not executing

Tags: css, image, hover

I want an image to slightly grow in size when hovering over it. I know it's pretty simple, but I have looked for a good hour over other examples and cannot seem to figure out what I am missing. I appreciate the help. These images are saved to my computer.

Scope

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<embed src="73797^alarmclock.mp3"; autostart="true"; loop="true"; hidden="true";/>

<body>

     <img src ="alarm clock2.jpg"/>

     <p>  Pulling the sheets into my body, I begin to sink back into the bed... 
          uggh... my alarm clock... time to get up..

         <img style = "position:absolute; top:300px; right: 0px; z-index:1" 
          src="computer.jpg"/>

         <IMG  ID="grow" STYLE= "position:absolute; TOP:1157px; LEFT:599px; 
          WIDTH:47px; z-index:2; HEIGHT:47px" SRC="icon2.gif"/> 

</body>

</html>
```

And here is the stylesheet.css

```
#grow:hover {
width: 100px;
height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use inline styles. Your problem is that inline styles are more prioritized than CSS. Put them in your `stylesheet.css` and it'll work.

Comment: Why are you using inline styles and CSS thats messy.

Comment: and everything not in quotation marks should be lowercase. did u create this in microsoft word or something?

Answer (score 2):

The **inline style** which declared in the HTML element has a higher priority than other css rules. So consider make your rules **`!important`** or move the inline style out.

Anyway, the `!important` rules are not recommended to use regularly. So you have better remove your inline styles and put them in `.css` files (or at least `<style>` element inside `<head>`)

Comment: It's highly inadvisable to use !important regularly, especially when he can fix it in a minute by stop using inline styles.

Comment: I agree with you, I just give him all available options. I Think I should include it in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it working. Pretty new to this stuff. No more inline styles.

Comment: @user2719596 this is not a recommended solution. It might work but its advise against it.

Answer (score 2):

Inline styles have priority over CSS i believe.

Change your CSS and HTML to the following:

```
#grow {
    position:absolute;
    top:1157px; 
    left:599px; 
    width:47px;
    z-index:2;
    height:47px
}
#grow:hover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<IMG  ID="grow" SRC="icon2.gif"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this style

```
#grow:hover {
width: 100px !important;
height: 150px !important;
}
```

Because you have written inline styles. In order to override it you need to add **`!important`** to the styles. Also try to write the html in lowercase and avoid unwanted spaces.

**The best thing you can do is avoid inline style and write style as below:**

```
#grow
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:1157px; 
    left:599px; 
    width:47px; 
    z-index:2; 
    height:47px
}

#grow:hover
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: This would work but it's highly inadvisable to use `!important` regularly, especially when he can fix it in a minute by stop using inline styles.